# TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found

Tags: python, text-mining

I need your help , I am working with text mining ,text classification,and when I want to convert my list of words into string of characters ,because countvec doesn't work with list,I get an error

```
    Data['FilteredArticle']=0.0
    for i in range (0,Data.shape[0]):
        DS=nlp(Data['Titre-Article'][i])
        Data['FilteredArticle'][i]=[ w for w in DS if w.is_alpha and not w.is_stop and not w.is_punct and len(w)>3] 
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(Data.FilteredArticle , Data.classe)
    Xtrain=" ".join(X_train)
    count_vect = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', token_pattern=r'\w{1,}')
    count_vect.fit(X_train)
```

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 Xtrain=" ".join(X_train)

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r65R2.png)

Comment: X_train it is a list of list, change it to list of strings

Comment: has your data for X_train been cleaned up correctly? It seems it should contain strings, but one of the data contains a list or perhaps you have a string starting with a '[' character in your data set?

Comment: How can I change it to list of strings ? because I tried with join() but I still have error, the X_train has been cleaned up correctly from all ponctuation

Comment: And when I run the count_Vect with X_train as a list ,I get this error;                                   
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'